# Javascript find select element in a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a table column with selects and text value cells like this:

```
<tr>
   <td data-key="data1">some text data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td data-key="data2">
      <select>
        <option>1_option</option>
        <option>2_option</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I need to grab the data depending on the type of data in the cell. I do it like this:

```
var obj = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function() {
            var $row = $(this);
            var localobj = {};
            var cell = $row.find(':nth-child(1)');
            dataattr = cell[0].getAttribute('data-key');
            var selectObject = cell.find("select");
            console.log(selectObject);
            if(selectObject){ // always true here, but I need false if there is no select in the cell
                localobj[dataattr] = selectObject.val();
            }else{
                localobj[dataattr] = cell.text();
            }
            return localobj;
        }).get();
```

It grabs selected values correctly but cannot get the text ones because it always returns true in my if evaluation. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: use `if(selectObject.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery wraps everything in it's own object container and therefore `selectObject` will **always** evaluate to true as it is an object that is not undefined or null.

You can simply check to make sure the object has at least 1 element via

```
if (selectObject.length > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```js
var tbl = $('#tblHours');

tbl.find('tr').each(function(){
   $(this).find('td').each(function(){
       alert($(this).find('select :selected').val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As
As explained by @Arvind Audacious, jQuery always returns a container. You cannot assume the result of the query is NULL. Instead, you need to check its length in order to verify if it has actually retrieved any elements. See code below for example:

```js
    $('#myTable tbody tr td').each(function(){
           var selectObject = $(this).find('select');
           if(selectObject.length == 0) {
             console.log($(this).text())
             } else {
             console.log(selectObject);
             }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking jQuery selector object won't work, as it will be always true. Checking the length of the selector return is the best approach for this. Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/r43dqqdy/1/

```
var obj = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function() {
var $row = $(this);
var localobj = {};

var td = $row.find('td').first();

var dataattr = td.attr('data-key');

var select = td.find('select');
if(select.length > 0){
    console.log(select);
    if(select.find('option:selected').length > 0){
        localobj[dataattr] = select.val();
    }
    else{
        // If not selected. What to do here??
    }
}
else{
  localobj[dataattr] = td.text();
}
return localobj;
}).get();
console.log(obj);
```